# Asp mvc 4 radiobuttonfor bind to array property

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, radiobuttonlist

I have an MVC project and a form contains a table of dynamic rows which contain some fields with radiobuttons.

I created the dynamic fields and radiobuttons as arrays. When I check one of the radios and then submit the form, the array property of the radios is always null. I've also tried this with form collection but it is also null.

Model:

```
public bool[] PrimaryContact { get; set; }
```

View: I've tried both razor radio and default radio

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(objModel => objModel.PrimaryContact) 
<input type="radio" name="PrimaryContact[]"/>
```

My interface is looks like this
[image]

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Your not giving the radio buttons a value. but this makes no sense anyway - you cannot bind a radio button to an array (it only posts back a single value) and radio buttons need to be grouped. And your not giving the buttons a value. You want a checkbox if your binding to a `bool`

Comment: thanks you are right i have to use checkbox for that and making them client select one of them at one, radio doesn't support my idea.